# Why Non commercial use / Unlicensed product with Shared Computer Activation?

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft-office, office365, windows-server-2016

I have Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus installed a few months ago on RDP computer.
In Group Policy enabled Shared Computer Activation, and it applied to installation:
[image]
But I can't use Office products because of (Non-Commercial Use) (Unlicensed Product) in the window title.

What should I do?

Comment: Please translate relevant parts of screenshots. That way, everyone that can read and write English can help you. :)

Comment: If you have problem with Office 365 licensing, then you made a mistake coming here. Not only Microsoft is the only entity that can resolve it for you, they are more than willing to lend a hand. They treat 365 customers like kings and queens.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same issue on an RDS server.
I did an Office online repair, afterwards you need to sign in to Office 365 to activate your license again for all users (or use Seamless SSO).

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution. I don't know how long it will work.
I tried online-repair, but it helped not.

At first, uninstall Office and restart a system.

Then download fresh install package from Portal and install it. Restart system.

Interest thing: some users still got messages about non-commercial, but open/close app few times fixed it.